# What are methods and tools for moderating large Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook

I moderate a large Facebook group. It's a casual joke group on a specific theme, with 1M+ members. It's still growing fast, and the FB moderation tools are increasingly difficult to use to moderate the group. Looking for any tips, suggestions or 'power user' hacks for moderating large groups, particularly:

- How to deal with 10k+ user approvals a day systematically. Spam join requests usually do a post/comment with their join request so those have to be weeded out
- How to take on moderators without diluting the principles and feel of the group
- How to take on moderators without them having access to lots of personal data and group specific data such as stats that I'd prefer to keep private
- To to stay on the right side of Facebook's 'Community Standards'

TIA!